# Jetty persistent sessions - write-only?

Tags: java, session, persistence, jetty, wicket

I have been trying to get Jetty's session persistence to work. It is in fact writing the sessions to disk, but it doesn't seem to read them back as my session data is all obliterated by the time my application gets a chance to read the session.

We're configuring it like so:

```
HashSessionManager sessionManager = new HashSessionManager();
sessionManager.setStoreDirectory(new File("sessions"));

// If I don't put in this next line, it seems like it "never" saves sessions to disk.
// Or at least I don't have the patience to wait however long it must take to do so.
sessionManager.setSavePeriod(5);//seconds

// Supposedly if you don't turn this on it can cause problems for some of the things
// Wicket puts in the session because Jetty would otherwise initialise the objects in
// the session before Wicket itself initialises.
sessionManager.setLazyLoad(true);

// ...
servletHandler.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler(sessionManager));
```

The documentation doesn't seem to mention any obvious pitfalls except for the one I have already stepped over in the code above by enabling lazy loading. But there are a lot of other sessions in that class and pretty much all of them are undocumented in the Javadoc, so it's hard to know where to go from here other than digging through their source code to find a potential bug...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question a day later. I tried adding a custom key-value pair into the session and discovered that it was persisted into the session fine. While doing so I also noticed that the size of the session file was steadily growing, which seemed particularly unusual if the whole session seemed to be getting purged every time the server was restarted!

So I wrote some code to dump all the session data and discovered that Wicket had multiple values in the session like this (only there were about 10 times more key-value pairs by the time I got this far):

```
Wicket:SessionUnbindingListener-com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1037224009=org.apache.wicket.session.HttpSessionStore$SessionBindingListener@5b3ab386
Wicket:SessionUnbindingListener-com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1306414591=org.apache.wicket.session.HttpSessionStore$SessionBindingListener@33048394
wibble=wobble
wicket:com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1037224009:session=com.acme.server.webui.ServerWebUISession@30e97557
wicket:com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1037224009:wicket:persistentPageManagerData - com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1037224009=org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$SessionEntry@20e39570
wicket:com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1306414591:currentUser=com.acme.server.auth.DefaultServerUser@2f16bbd7[id=2,name=admin,roles=[admin, user]]
wicket:com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1306414591:roles=admin, user
wicket:com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1306414591:session=com.acme.server.webui.ServerWebUISession@6b8cb5cd
wicket:com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1306414591:wicket:persistentPageManagerData - com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1306414591=org.apache.wicket.page.PageStoreManager$SessionEntry@517d59d0
```

This led me on a wild search for "com.acme.server.web.DispatcherServlet-1037224009". It turned out to be the value of getServletName() for the servlet. The Javadoc for getServletName() says that the servlet name will be the servlet's class name, however for Jetty this is in fact *not* the case - it also appends some kind of random number on the end. So it turns out to be a Jetty + Wicket peculiarity where Wicket puts the servlet name into the session keys and then Jetty doesn't generate the servlet names according to the API docs.

The fix was of course a one-liner to set a known name for the dispatcher servlet.

Comment: Wicket uses the filter/servlet name in the keys because you may have several wicket applications in one .war. Just like wicket-examples.war does. I cannot comment on the Jetty part.